# Include a list of allow ip address into specific location

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker-compose

I want to make my wordpress admin directory/files accessible only from my IP white list.

I want the list to be in other conf file because the list has more than 200 IPs.

Here is my default.conf. I use docker-compose.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location ~* /wp-login\.php|/wp-admin/((?!admin-ajax\.php).)*$ {
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/allowip.conf;
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

### result...

I am in the white list and when I access to mysite.com/wp-admin, my browser download the actual php files.

plus, I just realized no matter if you 'include' the allowip.conf or not, the setting in allowip.conf is active.

### My question

How do you apply a white list in a separate file to a certain directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location ~* /wp-login\.php|/wp-admin/((?!admin-ajax\.php).)*$ {
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/allowip.conf;
        deny all;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ahmed. Based on your code, I changed the location = /wp-login.php and now worked as desired. I hope this protect the admin area.